# Freeswitch command to add sip users

Tags: command, addition, freeswitch

Is there a command to add sip users in freeswitch as there is one in kamailio, i.e. like kamctl add [user] [password]?

Comment: In kamailio users are stored in DB and it makes sense to use script for adding/removing user, but in Freeswith all config are in xml config file and xml config file should be editable with text editor, so no sense to use/create any script for this.

Answer (score 1):

`add_user` script doesn't come with default installation. But its available in  [perl script](https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse/scripts/perl/add_user)

Download this script to your script path in freeswitch and you have to create a new user like `add_user 10001`

[Reference](http://voicebundle.com/creating-users-extensions-in-freeswitch-creating-sip-accounts-in-freeswitch-using-add_user-script)

Answer (score 0):

FreeSWITCH don't have any command for creating a user by command. But the task of creating default user is very simple.you can simply copy the default xml file from /usr/local/freeswitch/conf/directory/default directory and rename it and change the configuration as per your requirement.that's it now you are ready with new user.

Even in freeswitch you can write your own freeswitch command that can create new user in that.